# Bind custom component store config to ViewModel store

Tags: javascript, extjs, data-binding, extjs6

I'm writing a custom component in Ext JS which needs a store as a part of its configuration. I want to keep this store in the component's ViewModel, and I also want it to be bindable. Currently I have code like this:

```javascript
Ext.define('CustomComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'customcomponent',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'customcomponent'
    },
    config: {
        store: 'ext-empty-store'
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var store = Ext.getStore(this.getConfig('store'));
        this.lookupViewModel().set('myStore', store);
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.define('CustomComponentViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.customcomponent',
    data: {
        myStore: null
    }
});
```

This is not ideal for a number of reasons:

- The `store` config option isn't bindable.
- The store is contained in the `data` of the ViewModel, not the `stores`. This means it can't be accessed via the `getStore` method of the ViewModel.

To make the store bindable, I could write code like this:

```javascript
Ext.define('CustomComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'customcomponent',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'customcomponent'
    },
    config: {
        store: 'ext-empty-store'
    },
    publishes: 'store'
});

Ext.define('CustomComponentViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.customcomponent',
    data: {
        store: null
    },
    formulas: {
        myStore: function(get) {
            return Ext.getStore(get('store'));
        }
    }
});
```

This is not ideal either, though:

- The ViewModel is polluted with the `store` config, which is not necessarily an Ext.data.Store. It could be a store's ID or a config object. Essentially, it's an implementation detail, and I'd like to keep it out of the ViewModel where it will be inherited by every child component.
- The store is *still* not a part of the ViewModel's store configuration and so is *still* not accessible via `getStore`.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to set up my View and ViewModel (and ViewController, if it would help) so that I can meet these three criteria:

- The `store` config on the view is bindable.
- The `store` config option is not kept in the ViewModel, or is somehow prevented from polluting the ViewModels of the component's children.
- The store in the ViewModel is accessible via `getStore`.

Is it possible to meet all three of these criteria simultaneously? If not, what is the most canonical way to transform a bindable store config into a ViewModel store? The Ext JS source code doesn't use the View-ViewModel architecture to define components, so I can't just look at what they do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use the store like this.

```
Ext.define('CustomComponentViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.customcomponent',
    formulas: {
        myStore: function(get) {
            return Ext.getStore(get('store'));
        }
    },
    stores: {
        myStore: {
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'id'
                },
                {
                    name: 'name'
                },
                {
                    name: 'description'
                }
            ]
        }},

});    


Ext.define('CustomComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'customcomponent',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'customcomponent'
    },
    config: {
        bind: {
            store: '{myStore}'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're suggesting. How would this let the store be set by the component?

Comment: I think I may have been confused about what you needed. Glad you got it figured out though!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Ext JS 6.0.2 source code more thoroughly, I have come to the conclusion that meeting all three criteria I want is not possible without overriding or subclassing `Ext.app.ViewModel`. I'll go through the criteria one by one, and then discuss what I think is the best current practice.

## Criteria

### The `store` config must be bindable

This is actually accomplished by default; all config options are bindable. What I had meant when I said the store must be bindable was "binding to the `store` config will update the store in my ViewModel". The value of the `store` config will be sent to the ViewModel if the `publishes` option is set appropriately, i.e. `publishes: 'store'`. This will send the raw value of the `store` config back to the ViewModel as `store`, though, which is not what we want. I think the cleanest way to work around this is via the `applyConfigName` template method provided for each config option. Here's an example:

```
Ext.define('CustomComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'customcomponent',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'customcomponent'
    },
    config: {
        store: 'ext-empty-store'
    },
    publishes: 'store',
    applyStore: function(store) {
        return Ext.getStore(store);
    }
});
```

The `applyStore` function will be applied to the value of `store` before it gets set, transforming it from a store ID or config object into an actual store. This brings us to the second criterion:

### The `store` config option is not kept in the ViewModel

By using the `applyStore` template method we can keep the store config option out of our ViewModel. (Indeed, it even keeps it out of our View!) Instead the value of `store` which is published to our ViewModel is the actual store which it defines. Unfortunately, however, publishing config values adds them to the data object of the ViewModel, not the stores object. This brings us to the final criterion:

### The store in the ViewModel is accessible via `getStore`

This criterion is currently impossible to satisfy. The reason is two-fold:

#### `getStore` retrieves only stores added via the `stores` config option

In Ext JS 6.0.2, `getStore` retrieves stores by looking them up in the `storeInfo` private property of `Ext.app.ViewModel`. The `storeInfo` property is itself set via the `setupStore` private method, which is called only on each member of the `stores` config.

#### The `stores` config option only allows config objects

Unlike the `store` config of `Ext.grid.Panel`, the `stores` config option of `Ext.app.ViewModel` only allows the values of each store to be config objects; Store IDs and actual stores are not permitted. Setting the value to a binding directly seems like it works, e.g.:

```
Ext.define('CustomComponentViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.customcomponent',
    data: {
        dataStore: null
    },
    stores: {
        storeStore: '{dataStore}'
    }
});
```

But in actuality, the `storeStore` is a new `Ext.data.ChainedStore` which is configured with `source: dataStore`. This means that setting filters and sorters on `storeStore` will not affect `dataStore`, which is probably not what was desired.

The combination of these two restrictions means it is impossible to set a store in a ViewModel which can be retrieved with `getStore`.

## So what should I do?

I think that with the available options, the best practice is to give up the ability to retrieve the store with `getStore`. While this is an annoying inconsistency, it is less likely to cause subtle bugs the way that allowing an implicit `ChainedStore` might. This gives us our final code:

```
Ext.define('CustomComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'customcomponent',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'customcomponent'
    },
    config: {
        store: 'ext-empty-store'
    },
    publishes: 'store',
    applyStore: function(store) {
        return Ext.getStore(store);
    }
});

Ext.define('CustomComponentViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.customcomponent',
    data: {
        store: null
    }
});
```